# Excel Range.Formula is taking time to give an output in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, excel, vsto, vba

I have created an `Excel 2007 Addin` Application.

I am accessing a particular range formula but it is taking more time than the equivalent in `VBA`.

My code in `C#`

```
Excel.Range rng = Application.get_Range("D23:AB10023");
object[,] array = rng.Formula;
```

and the same code in `VBA`

```
Dim dataarray As Variant
dataarray = Sheet1.Range("$D$23:$AB$10023").Formula
```

Time in `VBA` is (HH:MM:SS:Millisec)

Before----->  20:51:26.34
After------>  20:51:26.52

Time in `C#` (Stop Watch Time)

Before getting formula---->00:00:00.0002964
after getting formula----->00:00:8.4754285

In `C#` it is taking around 8 second and in `VBA` it is taking less than a second.

Can you please let me know what the problem is?

Comment: The COM interop with Excel is notoriously slow.

Comment: [This page](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel) points out a couple perf-related things.

Comment: can i get some sort of alternative for that through C#.?
i just want to access the formula of the range in minimal time through C#.
if u have a solution please let me know.